# Managing Spring dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud

I'm using the Spring Boot framework with Gradle. I know that to include some Spring dependencies I can reference "starters" without explicitly defining the version; the version will be controlled by that version of Spring Boot I choose, which is the version of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin. Example (non-relevant Gradle code is omitted):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: BOOT_VERSION
        classpath group: 'io.spring.gradle', name: 'dependency-management-plugin', version: DEP_MGMT_VERSION
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Notice above that there are no explicit versions defined my for my application dependencies.

Now, let's say I want to include some Spring *Cloud* and Spring *Integration* dependencies. For example:

```
compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mqtt:some-version'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:some-other-version'
```

How can I ensure that the versions I use for those dependencies are compatible with my other Spring Boot dependencies? I cannot leave out the version, so it seems the Gradle plugin is not taking care of these dependencies (maybe it only takes care of those with group `org.springframework.boot`?).

To put it another way, is there a clean, safe method to ensure that *all* my Spring dependencies will work together, from Spring Boot, Spring Cloud etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Use the starters in your gradle script.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile ':spring-cloud-starter-config'
    compile ':spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    compile ':spring-boot-starter-integration'
}
```

https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/blob/master/README.md

For Spring Cloud, add a dependencyManagement section with the compatible Cloud-to-Boot versions. The documentation indicates which project versions are compatible with the corresponding Boot trains (1.4.x, 1.5.x, 2.x):

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom ':spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.M8'
  }
}
```

> Finchley builds and works with Spring Boot 2.0.x, and is not expected to work with Spring Boot 1.5.x.
>
> The Dalston and Edgware release trains build on Spring Boot 1.5.x, and are not expected to work with Spring Boot 2.0.x.
>
> The Camden release train builds on Spring Boot 1.4.x, but is also tested with 1.5.x.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/

Comment: For Spring Cloud, can one wildcard the version to consume bug fixes etc? For example `Finchley.+`.